# custom angular filter used on ng-option leaves blank options

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to filter out some options in a select element using angular.js. The problem is that for every item in the model that doesn't meet the filter criteria I get a blank option element in the select.

My questions are:

How can I fix the custom filter to remove the empty options?
Is there a way to modify the value of my ng-options directive to perform this filter more declaratively in the markup?

The code is below and you can also find it at http://jsfiddle.net/G4qkW/

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="myController">
    <select ng-model="militaryBranches" ng-options="m as m | coreBranches for m in militaryBranches">
        <option value="">Select Military Branch</option>
    </select>    
</div>
```

```
function myController($scope) {
    $scope.militaryBranches = [{
        BranchId: '1',
        Name: 'Air Force'
    },{ 
        BranchId: '2',
        Name: 'Army'
    },{
        BranchId: '3',
        Name: 'Coast Guard'
    },{
        BranchId: '4',
        Name: 'Marines'        
    },{
        BranchId: '5',
        Name: 'Navy'
    },{
        BranchId: '6',
        Name: 'National Guard 1'   
    },{
        BranchId: '7',
        Name: 'National Guard 2'
    },{
        BranchId: '8',
        Name: 'Some Other Branch'
    }];
}

var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.filter('coreBranches', function() {
    return function(item) {
         if (item.BranchId < 6) {
              return item.Name;
         }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have edited your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/G4qkW/5/

I guess you want the branches filtered out, not to display their names. You need to apply the filter to the collection, not to the name:

```
m.BranchId as m.Name for m in militaryBranches | coreBranches
```

To make this work, edit the filter like this:

```
app.filter('coreBranches',
function () {
    return function (items) {
        var filtered = [];
        angular.forEach(items, function (item) {
            if (item.BranchId < 6) {
                filtered.push(item);
            }
        });
        return filtered;        
    }
});
```